# "Access is denied" error while importing CSV to Power BI via Python

Tags: python, import, powerbi, ado.net

I'm trying to integrate python into my Power BI workflow. I was following [this tutorial on the Datacamp website](https://campus.datacamp.com/courses/introduction-to-python-in-power-bi/getting-started-with-python-in-power-bi?ex=3), but I'm having trouble importing a dataset.

I've opened the python scripting area, and my code is very simple:

```
import pandas as pd

print("Hello world")

dataset = pd.read_csv("sandbox\\data_science_practice\\introduction-to-python-in-power-bi\\Datasets\\consume.csv")

print(dataset)
```

**Note:** I've trimmed off the first part of the path for privacy

I've run the code snippet in Visual Studio Code with no issue. In Power BI, however, I'm hit with this error:

[image]

Can anyone help with what permissions it's referring to?

Answer (score 2):

Figured out the issue. I had installed python from the Microsoft store as per the suggestion for VS code, but while it worked really well with VS Code, it didn't work well with Power BI.

Answer (score 1):

on Power BI, you can try and click on Get data, then click Text/CSV and then finally on "Connect" button. This is to ensure that PowerBI has access to the file.

**If you can access it,** please ensure your Python script options are set correctly to your local installation path (Python home directory).

**If you cannot access it,** please go to **Data Source Settings** dialog, select the data source(s) and then click on **Edit Permissions...** button and ensure that the **Privacy Level** is set to **Public**.

**If none of that works, and you are using Anaconda** the hardest solution is to launch the PowerBI Desktop executable from the Anaconda Prompt **after activating the environment** in which you want to run the Python script. The command to use to launch Power BI Desktop is as follows:

`C:\Program Files\Microsoft Power BI Desktop\bin\PBIDesktop.exe`

At that point PowerBI Desktop opens and, repeating the steps from before to run the sample Python code, you should be ok.

NOTE: Please ensure you add Anaconda to System Environment Variable Path list:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\bin

If you are using a native virtual environment with `venv`, then try the same steps, but activate it before launching PowerBI from command line.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I turned off Windows firewalls for Domani, Private and Public netowrks, but got the same error, so perhaps that wasn't it?

All of my data is local to my machine. Would the firewall still have an effect?

Comment: Please check my edited answer, I have added more troubleshooting steps

Comment: I figured it out and added an answer. But thank you for your help in more troubleshooting!